# How can I 'ungroup' my SQL data without using recursion?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table that has data in an 'aggregated' or 'rolled up' format. All of our stored queries and views currently work at the 'unrolled up' level, and therefore joining this query on is particularly problematic for single values.

I am looking at ways to ungroup the data and have found a way to do it using a CTE with recursion, but this is prevented from saving it as a view, as the server will only allow a recursion of 100 and to alter this, would require the `OPTION` statement, which won't be possible to implement in the application that looks at this.

Is there another way to achieve this result and save it into a view for referencing?

Here's an example of the data:

```
+----+------------+------------+------+
| id | start date |  end date  | days |
+----+------------+------------+------+
|  1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-05 |    5 |
|  1 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-10 |    3 |
|  2 | 2023-12-30 | 2023-12-31 |    2 |
|  3 | 2023-02-05 | 2023-02-07 |    3 |
+----+------------+------------+------+
```

Here's my desired output:

```
+----+------------+------+
| id |    date    | days |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 | 2023-01-01 |    1 |
|  1 | 2023-01-02 |    1 |
|  1 | 2023-01-03 |    1 |
|  1 | 2023-01-04 |    1 |
|  1 | 2023-01-05 |    1 |
|  1 | 2023-01-08 |    1 |
|  1 | 2023-01-09 |    1 |
|  1 | 2023-01-10 |    1 |
|  2 | 2023-12-30 |    1 |
|  2 | 2023-12-31 |    1 |
|  3 | 2023-02-05 |    1 |
|  3 | 2023-02-06 |    1 |
|  3 | 2023-02-07 |    1 |
+----+------------+------+
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are the dates ddmmyyyy or mmddyyyy?

Comment: Long story short: you want a calendar table. If you have one, include the definition and sample in the question, and someone can give you code to use it. Also helpful to clarify on the exact data type of the date column (please tell me it's not varchar. That would be sad, and make this query much slower and more complicated than it needs to be.)

Comment: Sorry, dates are actually 'yyyy-mm-dd' - I've edited the question to reflect. Just to clarify @JoelCoehoorn - it's in `date` format.

Comment: Got it... then it's worth mentioning the values are **NOT** actually in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format. That's a convenience of your tooling. Rather, the actual format is a binary value that is efficient for storage and indexing, and not intended for humans to read.

Comment: You can use GENERATE_SERIES to apply on your table and create fake days.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of SQL Server you can use [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to break out a single row into multiple rows.

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  DATEADD(day, g.value, t.startDate) AS date,
  1 AS days
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(day, t.startDate, t.endDate) g;
```

In older versions you can use a [numbers generator function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) or a numbers table

Answer (score 1):

If `generate_series` is not an option, here we create an ad-hoc numbers table and perform a simple `JOIN`

```
Select A.ID
      ,EffectiveDate = dateadd(DAY,N,[Start Date])
 From YourTable A
 Join ( Select Top 500 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By 1/0) From master..spt_values n1 ) B
   on B.N<Days
```

Note: `master..spt_values` can be substituted with any table of adequate size.  Also, you can adjust the `top 500` to a more appropriate size

Comment: `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (SomeCalculationHere)` is probably faster than a join.